# global properties command line configuration of soap ui pro maven plugin

Tags: maven, plugins, soapui

I wanted to know if there is a way to override the global properties values in the soapui-settings.XML file by passing the values as command line parameters. This is with reference to using the soapUI pro maven plugin and not in using the command line version of soapUI.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use Maven properties as an intermediary.

Definite the SoapUI plugin something like:

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>com.smartbear.soapui</groupId>
            <artifactId>soapui-pro-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>.....</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <configuration>
                        <projectFile>.....</projectFile>
                        <projectProperties>
                            <value>property1=${soapui.value1}</value>
                        </projectProperties>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```

The in your pom define the properties:

```
<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <soapui.value1>soapui.actual.value</soapui.value1>
</properties>
```

Then you can call it from the commandline like:

```
mvn -Dsoapui.value1=soapui.other.value com.smartbear.soapui:soapui-pro-maven-plugin:test
```